# Case Conventions in wpf using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, naming-conventions, conventions

Is there a standard for case and naming conventions in wpf/mvvm that differs from C#?

I am accustomed to camelCase with the first character being lower case for private and upper case for public methods/properties.

In the sample MVVM code I have been examining I have seen a lot of leading _ characters, is this a holdover from another practice or is there a standard I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many sources for this, but here's the offical MSDN [Design Guidelines for Class Library Developers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czefa0ke%28VS.71%29.aspx). As for MVVM specific conventions, just follow C# design guidelines in your ViewModels and you should be good.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC leading _ is used for member variables. But regarding case conventions, just stay consistent and use something you find comfortable.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the naming convention at [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229012%28VS.100%29.aspx) and [the IDesign C# coding standard](http://www.idesign.net/idesign/download/IDesign%20CSharp%20Coding%20Standard.zip).